# "Generator noise" on boot

Tags: boot, intel-core-i7, noise

Since I bought this computer, every time I boot up, I hear this weird noise. You could compare it to a generator generating energy, or kind of like a formula 1 car, it goes from soft to loud and then it ends with a click.

This just happened when I started google chrome, my pc had been turned on for an hour, i just went to take a shower, a shave and breakfast, and when I came back, this happened.

So really, I want to make sure that this is nothing bad.
I'm assuming it's the processor, it's an Intel i7 920.

Comment: processors don't really emmit noises. can you add make and model of your computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your description, and this is just a guess, this could your hard disk starting to spin.

Comment: Power Management made my hard disk spin slower if the computer is idle, this is by default apparently, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I can remember such a noise as you described it, but can't really put it anywhere...

Might also be your CPU or GPU fan. Some GPU fans are turning at 100% during boot because the driver hasn't kicked in yet (to throttle them). Also check if a CD is in the drive.
Best thing would be, however, to open the PC (only if there's no guarantee on it anymore) and listen carefully from where the noise is coming.

Answer (score 1):

More that likely it's a fan.  Bearings go bad / out and it'll sound like a rocket taking off.  One thing to test if it's a bad fan is if you feel extra vibration.

Answer (score 0):

I got a call at work one day and the person described their computer as "ready for liftoff". We checked it out and turns out, there was a fan on the side of the case and they had that side of the case "face down" on the desk.

Answer (score 0):

I've definitely had a laptop with a fan that went bad and sounded sort of like that. I also had (same laptop, it was getting old at this point) a hard drive sound like that sporadically for a few days before it died completely. If you've had the computer a while, and you've never heard a noise like this, you might want to back up, just in case... ;)

On the other hand, if it's always sounded like that, you probably just have an unusually loud fan (and/or hard drive). I had a roommate in college with a computer like that. Was fun when I was trying to go to sleep, and he was pulling an all-nighter.

And... apparently it was already determined to be a loud hard drive. I can totally read comments. Still true in general, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. During startup boot, it made huge generator like noise, and then slowly stopped after the desktop comes. My PC was almost a year old with AMD Radeon on-board and 4GB RAM. So I checked the CPU whether the fan was making noise or any wire was obstructing the fan etc. But nothing was there. Then I came to know that the SMPS was the culprit. I replaced it with a new one and Voila! The problem solved.